# How to convert an array has special structure into an array of key-value pairs using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

This is the source of what i am trying to do:

1. source: a11993b18486c13240388
2. What i vae done so far:

```
$array = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $ref);
```

I am trying to convert the resulting $array into an object:

```
[
    "a",
    "11993",
    "b",
    "18486",
    "c",
    "13240388"
]
```

by grouping by 2 where first item is key and second is value:
Following is my desired outcome:

```
{
    "a"=>"11993",
    "b"=>"18486",
    "c"=>"13240388"
}
```

Maybe there is even a better way to do that?
I would appreciate if someone kindly guide me about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through array using `for` and in loop add values to new array.

```
$newArr = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i+=2)
    $newArr[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [a] => 11993
    [b] => 18486
    [c] => 13240388
)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/AOS6L)

---

Also if you want to do this using regex on string use

```
$ref = "a11993b18486c13240388";
preg_match_all("/([a-z])(\d+)/i", $ref, $matches);
$newArr = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/PsFlL)

Comment: this worked perfect, thanks! I was wondering if the same can be achieved through the regular expression so i can reduce it to just one line of code?

Comment: @jhondano Your content is in array but regex work on string. You should convert array to string and run regex and prepare target structure that cause write multiple line of code

Comment: i understand that but as you see in my question the source is string: a11993b18486c13240388, this needs to be split and grouped according to your example with for. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

try following :

```
$list = array(
"a",
"11993",
"b",
"18486",
"c",
"13240388"

);

$new_list = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i=$i+2) {

    $new_list[$list[$i]] = $list[$i+1];

}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($new_list); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This is exact duplicate of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i hope answer to your question is this, because you are looking for object:-

```
$arr=[
    "a",
    "11993",
    "b",
    "18486",
    "c",
    "13240388"
];

$arrForObj = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i+=2){
    $arrForObj[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}

$obj=(object)$arrForObj;
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($obj);
```